# Can't connect Vuetify to project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuetify.js, yarnpkg

I followed offical documentation to install vuetify, but I've got trouble with that.

When I am trying add vuetify to my project, I always get two types of errors:

First type:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!.
/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected newline.
   ╷
44 │ .app-main{
   │          ^
   ╵
  src\main\resources\static\js\pages\App.vue 44:10  root stylesheet
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loade
r/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&typ
e=style&index=0&lang=css&) 2:26-348
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules
/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/pages/App.vue
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/main.js

ERROR in ./src/main/resources/static/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/plugins/vuetify' in 'C:\Users\pingm\IdeaProjects\kursovaya\src\main\resources\static\js'
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/main.js 5:0-39 14:11-18
```

P.S
.app-main is my style class. Without vuetify it works fine.

Second type:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/plugins/vuetify' in 'C:\Users\pingm\IdeaProjects\kursovaya\src\main\resources\static\js'
 @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/main.js 5:0-39 13:11-18
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
Error from chokidar (/): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (/): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (/): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (/): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

I am not sure what the affects are on changing errors, but they are changing when I change code in **main.js** file

package.json

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import App from 'pages/App.vue'
import {connect} from "./util/ws";
import vuetify from '/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

if (frontendData.profile) {
    connect()
}

Vue.use(VueResource)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify,
    render: a => a(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js', 'main.js'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        compress: true,
        port: 8000,
        allowedHosts: [
            'localhost:8080'
        ],
        stats: 'errors-only',
        clientLogLevel: 'error'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
                        options: {
                            implementation: require('sass'),
                            sassOptions: {
                                fiber: require('fibers'),
                                indentedSyntax: true // optional
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving by adding this property to Webpack:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            plugins: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/plugins/vuetify.js')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', 'jsx', '.css'],
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    }
```

2. Main.js

```
import vuetify from 'plugins'
```